# UPDATE sql php variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

When I use these statements works:

```
$sql = "UPDATE nametable SET column = '$number' WHERE username = '$text'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

But, when I change 'column' to 'option1' like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE nametable SET '$option1' = '$number' WHERE username = '$text'";
```

The query doesn't work. What's wrong with $option1? :/

Thanks!

Comment: use ticks `\`` not quotes `'`

Answer (score 0):

column names must not be enclosed by quotes `'`

```
$sql = "UPDATE nametable SET " . $option1 . " = '$number' WHERE username = '$text'";
```